# Google App Engine Array List is Not a Supported Property Type

Tags: java, arrays, google-app-engine, collections

When I try to persist a two dimensional ArrayList I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cng_content: java.util.ArrayList is not a supported property type.
```

I am constructing a representation of a matrix using two array lists and trying to persist it to the data store.

```
    Key cngKey = KeyFactory.createKey("CNG", jsonCNG.cNGID);
    Entity cngEntity = new Entity("CNG", cngKey);
    cngEntity.setProperty("cng_name", jsonCNG.cNGName);
    cngEntity.setProperty("cng_type", jsonCNG.cNGType);
    cngEntity.setProperty("cng_content", cng);
```

In the code snippet cng is of type:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
```

I initially used

```
ArrayList<HashMap<Byte,Boolean>>
```

as the type of the object. However, found that HashMaps are not supported by GAE datastore. Further, I am not intending to query on the stored object. Just to store and retrieve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not querying, persist them as json or some other text format. Beware of maximum entity size.

Comment: this may be unrelated. However, do you know how to get the persisted object by its id? I am getting an error: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityNotFoundException: No entity was found matching the key: CNG("T78"), when set the key to Key cngKey = KeyFactory.createKey("CNG", "T78")

Comment: When you create your entity, you are creating it with `new Entity("CNG", cngKey);` which actually creates an Entity with a Kind "CNG" and an ancestor of cngKey (the id will get auto populated). Instead, you should be creating your entity with `new Entity(cngKey)`. Then you can lookup your object with  `datastore.get(cngKey)`.

Comment: Oops, look like Peter already answered this in a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233213/google-app-engine-getting-object-by-the-key

Comment: If your storing JSON I would look at converting to Text class.. as there is a length limit on datastore strings: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text

Answer (score 1):

The `setProperty(name, value)` method takes [supported java types](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types) and [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) of supported java types (this includes `ArrayList`). However collection inside a collection is not a supported type.

These are called multi-valued properties and have a purpose - each value of a collection gets it's own index entry so queries can actually find entities based on values inside collections.

In your case you'd be best serialising one dimension of a 2D list into a byte array and store it inside a [`Blob`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Blob), then store all blobs as `List<Blob>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use EmbeddedEntity which can be stored as a property on your entity.  Since you are only using 2D, set each array as a property on the EmbeddedEntity with the key being a number but represented in string format like "1", "2", "3".

More Specically:

```
Entity e = new Entity("2d");
EmbeddedEntity ee = new EmbeddedEntity();

ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
// add stuff to x

ArrayList<String> y = new ArrayList<String>();
// add stuff to y

ArrayList<String> z = new ArrayList<String>();
// add stuff to z

ee.setProperty("1", x);
ee.setProperty("2", y);
ee.setProperty("3", z);
e.setProperty("2dArray", ee);
```

I typed this out with out testing so may have syntax errors