# Google App Engine Getting Object by the Key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, persistence

I am stuck with geting a persisted object by its id. I am getting an error:

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityNotFoundException: No entity was found matching the key: CNG("T78")
```

I persist the object as below to the data store:

```
Key cngKey = KeyFactory.createKey("CNG", jsonCNG.cNGID);
Entity cngEntity = new Entity("CNG", cngKey);
cngEntity.setProperty("cng_name", jsonCNG.cNGName);
cngEntity.setProperty("cng_type", jsonCNG.cNGType);
cngEntity.setProperty("cng_content", cng);
```

Here cng is a json string. I set the key with a string: cNGID. I am trying to use the same id to get the object.

```
Key cngKey = KeyFactory.createKey("CNG", "T78")
```

and end up getting the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor [`new Entity("CNG", cngKey)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity#Entity%28java.lang.String,%20com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key%29) is defining the entity with kind and **parent key**. Then when you try to retrieve it you do not provide parent key: `KeyFactory.createKey("CNG", "T78")`. This does not work - you must either provide parent key in both places on not.

Note - defining entity parent is used when defining entity groups, which are in turn important when using transactions. You probably did not want that?

Instead you should just use `new Entity(cngKey)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have saved it to the datastore.

```
Datastore.put(cngEntity);
```

Comment: Actually, I save it to the data source. Sorry the code is missing.